# Tooltip and Click-Event for streamgeometry object

Tags: c#, wpf, events, drawing, tooltip

I'm drawing polybeziers using StreamGeometry and StreamGeometryContext. It works as it should but what I need is showing Tooltips or rising click events. I tried everything that came to my mind but I didn't find a solution that worked. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: How do you draw them? By a DrawingVisual or by a Path control? The latter would provide input handling.

Comment: I'm using DrawingContext.DrawGeometry function call

Comment: How about using Paths? Otherwise you may want to take a look at the [Hit Testing in the Visual Layer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097(v=vs.100).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Using Paths worked. Thank you so much! ;)